# Can we have a "read more" thing?

Tags: feature-request, answers, scrolling, answer-length

Some questions get too many long answers, and it makes scrolling to the bottom of the page very difficult.

For example, consider [this question on ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10550/50044), which is an effort to preserve all relevant content from the now-deprecated ELU Blog.

We have added links to each answer within the question body for quick access, but this is not applicable to the usual questions asked on main sites.

Can we have those looong answers default to a "snippet" state and expand only on clicking "read more"?

This is not necessary for all posts, but for only those posts having a lot of long answers. Look at Quora, for example. They make everything a snippet. I'm not asking for that extreme a thing, though.

Comment: Is there an actual use case for this, other than the occasional abuse of Meta?

Comment: @yannis Some sites like [workplace.se], [worldbuilding.se] (and more) often have too many answers and most of them too long. I will have to dig up some examples.

Comment: @NVZ Do you mean something like [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/44910/28789) with [the longest answer on WB](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/45273/28789) (so long that you can't fix any typos anymore because it reached the character limit)

Comment: @Secespitus Yeah, something like that could use a "click to read more" thingy. And thank you for the example.